# PGBrowser Get tinder token from facebook

Tags: php, web-scraping, mechanize

Rewriting this project: https://github.com/tarraschk/TinderAutoLike in PHP using PGBrowser.
My code :

```
<?php
require 'pgbrowser.php';

$b = new PGBrowser();
$tinder_url = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=fb464891386855067%3A%2F%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=user_birthday,user_photos,user_education_history,email,user_relationship_details,user_friends,user_work_history,user_likes&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&client_id=464891386855067";
$email = "***Email***";
$pass = "***Password***";
$page = $b->get($tinder_url);
$form = $page->form(0);
$form->set('email',$email);
$form->set('pass',$pass);
$page = $form->submit();
$submit = $page->form(0);
$page = $submit->submit();
var_dump($page);

?>
```

Problem : Not returning the access_token

Comment: What does it return

Comment: @RiggsFolly Smthg not related to what i want.. like it doesnt contain the access_token

Comment: What it DOES return might help us diagose what is wrong. So show us what does get returned!

Comment: @RiggsFolly here its limited to 30k character. so i post it on pastebin : http://pastebin.com/u8ckt6fN

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
<?php
require 'pgbrowser.php';

$b = new PGBrowser();
$tinder_url = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=fb464891386855067%3A%2F%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=user_birthday,user_photos,user_education_history,email,user_relationship_details,user_friends,user_work_history,user_likes&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&client_id=464891386855067";
$email = ""; //email here
$pass = ""; //pass here
$page = $b->get($tinder_url);
$form = $page->forms(0);
$form->set('email',$email);
$form->set('pass',$pass);
$page = $form->submit();
$submit = $page->forms(0);
$page = $submit->submit();
$page =  var_export($page,true);
$access_token = explode("access_token=",$page);
$access_token = explode("&expires_in",$access_token[1]);
echo $access_token[0];

?>
```

Comment: When I visit that link (e.g. in Firefox or Chrome), I can log in successfully and I receive a notification that I have already authorized Tinder. However, the URL does not change, and I don't see the access token in it. Did something change recently, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer! Open the developers tools in your browser and navigate to Network.. and u can see the access_token there! Not in the URL